# Coq - proof over empty range in Ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I have to prove a goal in the form:

```
forall x: ordinal_finType m, P x
```

I am currently in a case where I have `Hm: m = 0` in my stack, so this is essentially a `forall` over an empty set. How can I proceed in this case?
Using

```
case => x.
```

leaves me with

```
forall i : (x < m)%N, P i
```

but then of course I cannot use `rewrite Hm` as it fails with a dependent type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would need to rewrite with you zero hypothesis, actually the proof of emptiness is trivial due to the computational nature of the `<` operator in math-comp.

```
Lemma ordinal0P P : 'I_0 -> P.
Proof. by case. Qed.
```

or if you want:

```
Lemma avoid_rewrite_error: forall P m, m = 0 -> forall (i : 'I_m), P.
Proof. by move=> ? ? -> []. Qed.
```

Comment: Recall that dependent rewrite errors usually happen due not rewriting the definition of `P` themselves.